# Rename Azure Managed Disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are using Azure SQL template to deploy VMs with **managed disks** instead of storage blobs. Unfortunately, the auto generated managed disk names are not desired and we cannot find a way to change them in the deployment template.

Is there a way to rename a managed disk post deployment? (or during)

[image: How to rename Azure Managed disk?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is super easy to give them names. there's a `name` property for that...

```
"storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "offer": "WindowsServer",
        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
        "version": "latest"
    },
    "osDisk": {
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "name": "somename" <<< THIS IS IT
    }
},
```

I'm not sure that its possible to rename after you've created the disk. might be possible if you create a managed disk out of managed disk and you would be able to supply the name for the new one.

Comment: Thank you! The default SQL VM template was missing this property and I was not sure if it was taken into consideration. I will give it a try.